# I have XmL that needs to be parsed in a c# object. Xml has my api key and I need it in my c# controller class

Tags: c#, json, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I need the xml to be converted into c# object

This is the xml api key I am trying to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok" version="1.0">
    <api_key>57173e1d727788c372e91c115e8e2ff6</api_key>
    <version>4</version>
</rsp>
```

C# class where i need to use that api as an object 
I have took my password and api key out of the info.

```
public static string GetApiKey()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("accept-charset", "utf-8");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            //parse to get apikey

                return response.Content;
            string apikey = "";

            return apikey;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you in fact need to "convert the XML into an object", or do you just need to get the value of the `api_key` element as a string from the xml?

Comment: @EdPlunkett ... Yes, I just need the value of the api_key as a stringfrom the xml

Comment: @EdPlunkett i used post man to the that part of code

Comment: @Micheal you can do this in one of two ways, you can read the value of api-key direct from the XML as Ed Plunkett has shown you in his answer, or you could deserialise the XML into a c# object and use this object to do the necessary. I would imagine since you dont need any value but the API-key from the XML deserialising the object would be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the XML string, this is trivial.

1. Parse the XML.
2. Get the `rsp` element from the XML.
3. Get the `api_key` element from the `rsp` element.
4. Take the `api_key` element's `Value` property.

Like so:

```
 var xml = response.Content;
 var apiKey = XDocument.Parse(xml).Element("rsp").Element("api_key").Value;
```

Comment: yeah but how do i name the xml a String?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: its coming back hard coded and  the api key in xml is only good for 60 mins then changed

Comment: Then request it again.

Comment: Okay tell me where the xml string is and how to grab it

Comment: My best guess is that the XML string is in `response.Content`, as depicted in my answer. If it isn't there, *you tell me* where it is. I'm not sitting at your computer. You are.

Comment: oh so var xml.resonse.content is garbing the xml string right?

Comment: That's a somewhat informed guess on my part. You'll have to confirm that for yourself. You pasted some XML into your question. I don't know where it's from. You, presumably, remember where you got it from. Wherever you found it last time, go there again.